# Generating Fibonacci numbers until reaching some point in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, fibonacci

My code generates Fibonacci numbers in a recursive function with parameter `$n` which is the position of the wanted number.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

class Fibonacci {

      public $cache = array(0=>0, 1=>1);
      /**
       * Generates until reaching the given position ($n) Fibonacci number.
       * @param type $n int
       * @return type array
       */
      public function memoized($n)
       {
            if (!isset($this->cache[$n])) {
                $this->cache[$n] = $this->memoized($n - 1) + $this->memoized($n - 2);
            }
            return $this->cache[$n];
       }
}

$fib = new Fibonacci();

echo $fib->memoized(8);
```

I want to return an array of all generated Fibonacci numbers until reaching the limit but it somehow doesn't work if I just use `return $this->cache;` it returns array (nested array in array in array... etc) but not what I need.

Comment: Also add sample data, what you  get, and what you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to return the array at the end of the process???

I ran your code and it looks fine:

```
array(9) {
[0]=>    int(0)
[1]=>    int(1)
[2]=>    int(1)
[3]=>    int(2)
[4]=>    int(3)
[5]=>    int(5)
[6]=>    int(8)
[7]=>    int(13)
[8]=>    int(21)
```

}

These are the Fibonacci numbers you want.

If you add the following to the end of your code, then you will see the full result; even though using a public field in a class is generally a bad idea:

```
echo $fib->memoized(8);
var_dump($fib->cache);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that to calculate the *n*th Fibonacci number, you need to return a *number* rather than an array from your recursive function. Therefore, the final caller will be receiving a number. If you'd like to return an array at the end, simply wrap the recursive function in an outer function as follows:

```
class Fibonacci {
    private $cache = [0, 1];

    public function fib($n) {
        $this->memoized($n);
        return $this->cache;
    }

    private function memoized($n) {
        if (!isset($this->cache[$n])) {
            $this->cache[$n] = $this->memoized($n - 1) + $this->memoized($n - 2);
        }

        return $this->cache[$n];
    }
}

print_r((new Fibonacci())->fib(26));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 8
    [7] => 13
    [8] => 21
    [9] => 34
    [10] => 55
    [11] => 89
    [12] => 144
    [13] => 233
    [14] => 377
    [15] => 610
    [16] => 987
    [17] => 1597
    [18] => 2584
    [19] => 4181
    [20] => 6765
    [21] => 10946
    [22] => 17711
    [23] => 28657
    [24] => 46368
    [25] => 75025
    [26] => 121393
)
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because recursion. Please take a look at this solution which I found here on Stackoverflow. It returns an array with Fibonacci numbers. The amount you can adjust in the function.

```
    function fibonacci($n,$first = 0,$second = 1) {
    $fib = [$first,$second];
    for($i=1;$i<$n;$i++) {
    $fib[] = $fib[$i]+$fib[$i-1];
    }
    return $fib;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r(fibonacci(50));
echo "</pre>";
```